# UIWebView differences between ios4 and ios5

Tags: ios, uiwebview

i'm using UIWebview to display a local html page.
i tried this

```
text<span><span/>text
```

in iOS5, it's       "texttext",

but in iOS4, it's   "text text".

there is a space,and i want to remove this little space.

any help is appreciated,thanks,

and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake in a `span` tag. Should be `<span></span>`. Is it helping? If not, you can manually change CSS params.